# Grouping by HH:MM in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I wish to group my query by only the `HH:MM` in the `datetime` column

Table Name: `events`

Column Name: `Event_Date`

Rows:

```
2017-07-01 19:00
2017-07-02 20:30
2017-07-06 20:30
2017-07-09 21:00
2017-07-14 19:00
2017-07-23 23:30
```

As the group by is on the `HH:MM` I would expect to return 4 results:

```
19:00
20:30
21:00
23:30
```

Many thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
select date_format(Event_Date, '%H:%i')
from events
group by date_format(Event_Date, '%H:%i')
```

Comment: This wouldn't work. As this would be Hour and Month wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following group by the `HOUR` and `MINUTE`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Event_Date, '%H:%i')
FROM events 
GROUP BY HOUR(Event_Date), MINUTE(Event_Date)
```

This would return values like what you're after like:

```
19:00
20:30
21:00
23:30
```